# How to handle error from $sce.trustAsResourceUrl

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, forms, form-post, http-post

I'm trying to access an API that returns the PDF document upon success. I'm calling this API from my HTML code using $sce.trustAsResourceUrl.
This **getStatement** API will return JOSN error message if it fails and I'm wondering how to handle that error message in my Angular code.

**My HTML Code**

```
<form id="statementFrm" action="{{serviceURL}}" method="post" target="_blank">
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('statementFrm').submit();" >View Online Version</a>
</form>
```

**Javascipt Code**

```
$scope.serviceURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl( 'http://localost:3090/getStatement' );
```

Comment: I don't quite get the question, what do you want to do with the error message?

Comment: I wanted a way to handle the error message thrown by the API. As soon as user clicks the hyperlink new tab will be opened and it shows the content returned by the API. I wanted to display only the successful response on the new tab and wanted to handle the error message.

Comment: Okay, if you are getting a error JSON back into the `$scope.serviceURL` then you can just show the error message wherever you want. try this if you use bootstrap (assuming errorMessageis a property). `<div  class="warning" role="alert" ng-show="serviceURL.errorMessage.length > 0"><div><span>{{serviceURL.errorMessage}}</span></div></div>`

Comment: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl is to escape the url so that Angular will consider this as safe URL and the escaped url is stored in $scope.serviceURL. $scope.serviceURL doesn't contain the value returned by the API. Instead the value returned by API is displayed directly in the new tab opened.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no direct way to handle this error and instead the service needs to respond with proper error message in HTML format.